# MySQL any way to import a huge (32 GB) sql dump faster?

Tags: mysql, backup, innodb, mysqldump

I have this huge 32 GB SQL dump that I need to import into MySQL. I haven't had to import such a huge SQL dump before. I did the usual:

```
mysql -uroot dbname < dbname.sql
```

It is taking too long. There is a table with around 300 million rows, it's gotten to 1.5 million in around 3 hours. So, it seems that the whole thing would take 600 hours (that's 24 days) and is impractical. So my question is, is there a faster way to do this?

## Further Info/Findings

1. The tables are all InnoDB and there are no foreign keys defined. There are, however, many indexes.
2. I do not have access to the original server and DB so I cannot make a new back up or do a "hot" copy etc.
3. Setting `innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit = 2` as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73067/1117796) seems to make no (clearly visible/exponential) improvement.
4. Server stats during the import (from MySQL Workbench): https://imgflip.com/gif/ed0c8.
5. MySQL version is 5.6.20 community.
6. innodb_buffer_pool_size = 16M and innodb_log_buffer_size = 8M. Do I need to increase these?

Comment: @Bert the server has 8 GB of RAM most of which is just unused. Can't add more storage either. How would that help? Is it really the write operations that are so slow?

Comment: @ChrisS no, the CPU usage is 3 to 4%. I'm not sure what the bottleneck is. I'm thinking it's the indexes. How would one find/confirm the bottleneck?

Comment: A 32GB database dump cannot really be considered to be "huge". I'm trying to find information about importing multi-terrabyte databases, and keep finding questions about databases I would consider to be quite small.

Answer (score 171, accepted):

Percona's Vadim Tkachenko made this fine Pictorial Representation of InnoDB

[image: InnoDB Architecture]

You definitely need to change the following

```
innodb_buffer_pool_size = 4G
innodb_log_buffer_size = 256M
innodb_log_file_size = 1G
innodb_write_io_threads = 16
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit = 0
```

Why these settings ?

- [innodb_buffer_pool_size](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_buffer_pool_size) will cache frequently read data
- [innodb_log_buffer_size](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_log_buffer_size) : Larger buffer reduces write I/O to Transaction Logs
- [innodb_log_file_size](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_log_file_size) : Larger log file reduces checkpointing and write I/O
- [innodb_write_io_threads](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_write_io_threads) : Service Write Operations to `.ibd` files. According to [MySQL Documentation on `Configuring the Number of Background InnoDB I/O Threads`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-performance-multiple_io_threads.html), each thread can handle up to 256 pending I/O requests. Default for MySQL is 4, 8 for Percona Server. Max is 64.
- [innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit)

  - In the event of a crash, both 0 and 2 can lose once second of data.
  - The tradeoff is that both 0 and 2 increase write performance.
  - I choose 0 over 2 because 0 flushes the InnoDB Log Buffer to the Transaction Logs (ib_logfile0, ib_logfile1) once per second, with or without a commit. Setting 2 flushes the InnoDB Log Buffer only on commit. [*There are other advantages to setting 0 mentioned by @jynus, a former Percona instructor*](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/74438/877).

Restart mysql like this

```
service mysql restart --innodb-doublewrite=0
```

This disables the InnoDB Double Write Buffer

Import your data. When done, restart mysql normally

```
service mysql restart
```

This reenables the InnoDB Double Write Buffer

Give it a Try !!!

SIDE NOTE : [You should upgrade to 5.6.21 for latest security patches](https://aws.amazon.com/security/security-bulletins/mysql-5-5-and-5-6-security-advisory/).

Comment: I made a linux bash script for it, lowered some values to work inside vagrant with lower memory https://gist.github.com/OZZlE/57d550c3cc1c1ff17481e465e4f6d674

Comment: @MonsterMMORPG innodb_write_io_threads came into existence starting in MySQL 5.1.38. If you are using MySQL 5.0 up to 5.1.37, that's why you don't see it. See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_write_io_threads

Comment: @MonsterMMORPG Just for completeness, Percona had that option in Percona Server 5.0 in its InnoDB/XtraDB before MySQL made it available in 5.1.38 by means of the InnoDB Plugin..

Comment: It didn't work to add --innodb-doublewrite=0 to service start for me, I had to run the server manually with "/usr/sbin/mysqld --daemonize --pid-file=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid --skip-innodb-doublewrite"

Comment: It simply works...

Comment: Without: Query OK, 40688878 rows affected, 0 warnings (2 hours 39 min 30.84 sec)
With: Query OK, 40688878 rows affected, 0 warnings (8 min 3.49 sec) - local csv import on 4c 16gb SSD VM.

Comment: you can speed it up further by starting mysqld with eatmydata, eg `eatmydata mysqld --innodb-doublewrite=0 --innodb-flush-method=fsync` , benchmarks show a nearly 60% performance improvement on the MySQL benchmark testsuite: https://github.com/stewartsmith/libeatmydata#performance-improvements

Comment: Well, this did exactly nothing on an AmazonLinux2 server with mysql 5.7.41 - I had to use less ram, but essentially the same otherwise.   A 22min process finished in 22 minutes again.

Answer (score 17):

Do you really need the entire database to be restored? If you don't, my 2c:

You can extract specific tables to do your restore on "chunks". Something like this:

```
zcat your-dump.gz.sql | sed -n -e '/DROP TABLE.*`TABLE_NAME`/,/UNLOCK TABLES/p' > table_name-dump.sql
```

I did it once and it took like 10 minutes to extract the table I needed - my full restore took 13~14 hours, with a 35GB (gziped) dump.

The `/pattern/,/pattern/p` with the `-n` parameter makes a slice "between the patterns" - including them.

Anyways, to restore the 35GB I used an AWS EC2 machine (c3.8xlarge), installed Percona via yum (Centos) and just added/changed the following lines on `my.cnf`:

```
max_allowed_packet=256M
wait_timeout=30000
```

I think the numbers are way too high, but worked for my setup.

Comment: no parameter name as wait_timeout

Answer (score 6):

The fastest way to import your database is to copy the ( .frm, .MYD, .MYI ) files if MyISAM, directly to the /var/lib/mysql/"database name".

Otherwise you can try : `mysql > use database_name; \. /path/to/file.sql`

Thats another way to import your data.

Comment: This is not called "import" and it is not safe between MySQL versions. Don't do this until you go with all other options.

Answer (score 6):

One way to help speed up the import is to lock the table while importing.  Use the --add-locks option to mysqldump.

```
mysqldump --add-drop-table --add-locks --database db > db.sql
```

or you could turn on some useful parameters with [--opt](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysqldump.html#option_mysqldump_opt) this turns on a bunch of useful things for the dump.

```
mysqldump --opt --database db > db.sql
```

If you have another storage device on the server, then use that - copying from one device to another is a way to speed up transfers.

You can also filter out tables that are not required with [--ignore-table](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysqldump.html#option_mysqldump_ignore-table)

Comment: It's worth noting that (at least in mysqldump 8) `--opt` is enabled by default.

Answer (score 2):

This is how to set [RolandoMySQLDBA](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/877/rolandomysqldba) configuration in linux:

1. Open mysql conf file in your favourite text editor:

   `sudo vi /etc/mysql/my.conf`
2. Type the following configuration at the end of the file:

```
    [mysqld]
    innodb_buffer_pool_size = 4G
    innodb_log_buffer_size = 256M
    innodb_log_file_size = 1G
    innodb_write_io_threads = 16
    innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit = 0
    innodb_doublewrite = 0
```

3. Save the file and run this command in mysql:

   `set global innodb_fast_shutdown = 0`

   you can see the new configuration with @@ followed by command in mysql:

   `select @@innodb_buffer_pool_size;`

   similarly with other commands
4. Restart mysql:

   `service mysql restart`
5. Restore your database state:

   `mysql -u username -p database_name < /path/to/file.sql`

I had to import 5.8GB of data which took me 40min with the pc configuration of inter corei5 2.5GHZ and 16gb ram