# Export and Import large database from one rds of amazon to newly created amazon rds

Tags: mysql, mysqldump, amazon-rds, amazon-ec2, linux

We are facing some issue. We would like to export and import mysql database "xyz" from old rds say xyz-rds to newly created rds say abc-rds (mysql).

We are approaching common method taking full export of xyz database using mysql command and which is too much of time.

Actually database size is of 45GB . from one hour we exported only 2 GB  of data so , if we calculate it will take around 20 hours to export whole database. Which will be tedious, So please suggest any solution to import and export database as much quickly as possible. Like say maximum of 2 hours.

Note: We are running old rds with 40GB RAM and new one with 20 GB RAM.

Comment: Can you backup the xyz-rds database and restore it to abc-rds?  If so, that should greatly reduce the time spent on moving the database.

Comment: Yeah backup only taking too much.. time.. by mysql command.

is there any alternative and other methods for taking backup.. ? other than is ?

Answer (score 1):

You could just use the RDS feature "Restore to point in time", which will create a full point-in-time snapshot of your current RDS instance:

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_PIT.html

Answer (score 1):

There are few simple solutions.

## Snapshot and restore

Take a Snapshot of the old RDS and create your new RDS from this snapshot.
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_CreateSnapshot.html
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_RestoreFromSnapshot.html

## Mydumper

Use mydumper to backup and myloader for restore the db. This will be faster than native mysqldump.
http://centminmod.com/mydumper.html

## Tune the parameter

For Faster restore use this parameter.
[MySQL any way to import a huge (32 GB) sql dump faster?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/83125/mysql-any-way-to-import-a-huge-32-gb-sql-dump-faster/83385#83385)