# Importing huge dumps into a mysql server 5.5

Tags: mysql, mysqldump, import

I want to import a couple of huge `.sql` dumps (~600G each) into a mysql server 5.5 running on an Ubuntu 14.04.

The machine has about 8G of RAM allocated to it;

The previous machine had 128G;

Storage space considerations aside, what else should I take into account before performing the mysql import command?

Comment: Why start on such and old OS/MySQL version?

Comment: also [read this entry](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/83125/mysql-any-way-to-import-a-huge-32-gb-sql-dump-faster)

Comment: My previous (legacy) db is on `5.5` and I want to maintain the same version for the time being

Comment: InnoDB or MyISAM or both?

Comment: Just InnoDB ...

Answer (score 1):

If your database tables have them, it's always best to drop indices and recreate them after the import. Also, disable foreign keys temporarily by executing `SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;` (and `SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=1;` afterwards). This will speed up your import (though by how much is hard to tell).

Comment: Check the .sql files; those steps may be built in.

Answer (score 0):

For large-scale backup and restore, a physical backup is more appropriate, to copy the data files in their original format that can be restored quickly, and recommends the MySQL Enterprise mysqlbackup utility. 
-- http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysqldump.html#mysqldump-performance

Find Detailed Answer here: https://forums.mysql.com/read.php?24,645437,645443#msg-645443