# How can I tune my MySQL server to bulk import XML file (42 GB)?

Tags: mysql, innodb

I have a 40GB xml file which needs to be loaded into the db. Currently we are not sure about PK/FK relationships or schema details. So I am just loading them up without any indexes or keys. Every time I load it, I get the following error.

```
mysql> LOAD XML INFILE '/var/lib/mysql-files/myfile.xml' INTO TABLE my_tbl ROWS IDENTIFIED BY '<entry>';
ERROR 2013 (HY000): Lost connection to MySQL server during query
```

MySQL version is 8.0.23 running on Ubuntu 20.04

```
mysql> select version();
+-------------------------+
| version()               |
+-------------------------+
| 8.0.23-0ubuntu0.20.04.1 |
+-------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

$ cat /etc/lsb-release
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=20.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=focal
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS"
```

Details of the file I want to bulk load

```
$ sudo du -sh /var/lib/mysql-files/myfile.xml
42G     /var/lib/mysql-files/myfile.xml

$ sudo grep '<entry>' /var/lib/mysql-files/myfile.xml | wc -l
5659877

$ sudo wc -l /var/lib/mysql-files/myfile.xml
1906171631 /var/lib/mysql-files/myfile.xml
```

The xml has 67 tags. The create table statement is as follows. The reason for `TEXT` is because of unknown number of characters per column, and the data type. These are yet to be clarified by the client, so not exactly in my hands right now.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS my_tbl (
    `col1` TEXT,
    `col2` TEXT,
    ...
    `col67` TEXT
);
```

I referred to this answer here - [MySQL any way to import a huge (32 GB) sql dump faster?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/83125/mysql-any-way-to-import-a-huge-32-gb-sql-dump-faster) and made some changes to my variables and still I am not able to import my file. I keep running out of RAM (16 GB).

Custom variables in `/etc/mysql/my.cnf` (Even `innodb_buffer_pool_size = 4G` didn't work)

```
innodb_buffer_pool_size = 2G
innodb_log_buffer_size = 256M
innodb_log_file_size = 1G
innodb_write_io_threads = 16
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit = 0
```

I have also tried both with and without the following option, which still eats up my RAM.

```
service mysql restart --innodb-doublewrite=0
```

These are my settings for innodb variables.

```
mysql> show variables like '%innodb%';
+------------------------------------------+------------------------+
| Variable_name                            | Value                  |
+------------------------------------------+------------------------+
| innodb_adaptive_flushing                 | ON                     |
| innodb_adaptive_flushing_lwm             | 10                     |
| innodb_adaptive_hash_index               | ON                     |
| innodb_adaptive_hash_index_parts         | 8                      |
| innodb_adaptive_max_sleep_delay          | 150000                 |
| innodb_api_bk_commit_interval            | 5                      |
| innodb_api_disable_rowlock               | OFF                    |
| innodb_api_enable_binlog                 | OFF                    |
| innodb_api_enable_mdl                    | OFF                    |
| innodb_api_trx_level                     | 0                      |
| innodb_autoextend_increment              | 64                     |
| innodb_autoinc_lock_mode                 | 2                      |
| innodb_buffer_pool_chunk_size            | 134217728              |
| innodb_buffer_pool_dump_at_shutdown      | ON                     |
| innodb_buffer_pool_dump_now              | OFF                    |
| innodb_buffer_pool_dump_pct              | 25                     |
| innodb_buffer_pool_filename              | ib_buffer_pool         |
| innodb_buffer_pool_in_core_file          | ON                     |
| innodb_buffer_pool_instances             | 8                      |
| innodb_buffer_pool_load_abort            | OFF                    |
| innodb_buffer_pool_load_at_startup       | ON                     |
| innodb_buffer_pool_load_now              | OFF                    |
| innodb_buffer_pool_size                  | 2147483648             |
| innodb_change_buffer_max_size            | 25                     |
| innodb_change_buffering                  | all                    |
| innodb_checksum_algorithm                | crc32                  |
| innodb_cmp_per_index_enabled             | OFF                    |
| innodb_commit_concurrency                | 0                      |
| innodb_compression_failure_threshold_pct | 5                      |
| innodb_compression_level                 | 6                      |
| innodb_compression_pad_pct_max           | 50                     |
| innodb_concurrency_tickets               | 5000                   |
| innodb_data_file_path                    | ibdata1:12M:autoextend |
| innodb_data_home_dir                     |                        |
| innodb_deadlock_detect                   | ON                     |
| innodb_dedicated_server                  | OFF                    |
| innodb_default_row_format                | dynamic                |
| innodb_directories                       |                        |
| innodb_disable_sort_file_cache           | OFF                    |
| innodb_doublewrite                       | OFF                    |
| innodb_doublewrite_batch_size            | 0                      |
| innodb_doublewrite_dir                   |                        |
| innodb_doublewrite_files                 | 0                      |
| innodb_doublewrite_pages                 | 0                      |
| innodb_extend_and_initialize             | ON                     |
| innodb_fast_shutdown                     | 1                      |
| innodb_file_per_table                    | ON                     |
| innodb_fill_factor                       | 100                    |
| innodb_flush_log_at_timeout              | 1                      |
| innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit           | 0                      |
| innodb_flush_method                      | fsync                  |
| innodb_flush_neighbors                   | 0                      |
| innodb_flush_sync                        | ON                     |
| innodb_flushing_avg_loops                | 30                     |
| innodb_force_load_corrupted              | OFF                    |
| innodb_force_recovery                    | 0                      |
| innodb_fsync_threshold                   | 0                      |
| innodb_ft_aux_table                      |                        |
| innodb_ft_cache_size                     | 8000000                |
| innodb_ft_enable_diag_print              | OFF                    |
| innodb_ft_enable_stopword                | ON                     |
| innodb_ft_max_token_size                 | 84                     |
| innodb_ft_min_token_size                 | 3                      |
| innodb_ft_num_word_optimize              | 2000                   |
| innodb_ft_result_cache_limit             | 2000000000             |
| innodb_ft_server_stopword_table          |                        |
| innodb_ft_sort_pll_degree                | 2                      |
| innodb_ft_total_cache_size               | 640000000              |
| innodb_ft_user_stopword_table            |                        |
| innodb_idle_flush_pct                    | 100                    |
| innodb_io_capacity                       | 200                    |
| innodb_io_capacity_max                   | 2000                   |
| innodb_lock_wait_timeout                 | 50                     |
| innodb_log_buffer_size                   | 268435456              |
| innodb_log_checksums                     | ON                     |
| innodb_log_compressed_pages              | ON                     |
| innodb_log_file_size                     | 1073741824             |
| innodb_log_files_in_group                | 2                      |
| innodb_log_group_home_dir                | ./                     |
| innodb_log_spin_cpu_abs_lwm              | 80                     |
| innodb_log_spin_cpu_pct_hwm              | 50                     |
| innodb_log_wait_for_flush_spin_hwm       | 400                    |
| innodb_log_write_ahead_size              | 8192                   |
| innodb_log_writer_threads                | ON                     |
| innodb_lru_scan_depth                    | 1024                   |
| innodb_max_dirty_pages_pct               | 90.000000              |
| innodb_max_dirty_pages_pct_lwm           | 10.000000              |
| innodb_max_purge_lag                     | 0                      |
| innodb_max_purge_lag_delay               | 0                      |
| innodb_max_undo_log_size                 | 1073741824             |
| innodb_monitor_disable                   |                        |
| innodb_monitor_enable                    |                        |
| innodb_monitor_reset                     |                        |
| innodb_monitor_reset_all                 |                        |
| innodb_numa_interleave                   | OFF                    |
| innodb_old_blocks_pct                    | 37                     |
| innodb_old_blocks_time                   | 1000                   |
| innodb_online_alter_log_max_size         | 134217728              |
| innodb_open_files                        | 4000                   |
| innodb_optimize_fulltext_only            | OFF                    |
| innodb_page_cleaners                     | 4                      |
| innodb_page_size                         | 16384                  |
| innodb_parallel_read_threads             | 4                      |
| innodb_print_all_deadlocks               | OFF                    |
| innodb_print_ddl_logs                    | OFF                    |
| innodb_purge_batch_size                  | 300                    |
| innodb_purge_rseg_truncate_frequency     | 128                    |
| innodb_purge_threads                     | 4                      |
| innodb_random_read_ahead                 | OFF                    |
| innodb_read_ahead_threshold              | 56                     |
| innodb_read_io_threads                   | 4                      |
| innodb_read_only                         | OFF                    |
| innodb_redo_log_archive_dirs             |                        |
| innodb_redo_log_encrypt                  | OFF                    |
| innodb_replication_delay                 | 0                      |
| innodb_rollback_on_timeout               | OFF                    |
| innodb_rollback_segments                 | 128                    |
| innodb_sort_buffer_size                  | 1048576                |
| innodb_spin_wait_delay                   | 6                      |
| innodb_spin_wait_pause_multiplier        | 50                     |
| innodb_stats_auto_recalc                 | ON                     |
| innodb_stats_include_delete_marked       | OFF                    |
| innodb_stats_method                      | nulls_equal            |
| innodb_stats_on_metadata                 | OFF                    |
| innodb_stats_persistent                  | ON                     |
| innodb_stats_persistent_sample_pages     | 20                     |
| innodb_stats_transient_sample_pages      | 8                      |
| innodb_status_output                     | OFF                    |
| innodb_status_output_locks               | OFF                    |
| innodb_strict_mode                       | ON                     |
| innodb_sync_array_size                   | 1                      |
| innodb_sync_spin_loops                   | 30                     |
| innodb_table_locks                       | ON                     |
| innodb_temp_data_file_path               | ibtmp1:12M:autoextend  |
| innodb_temp_tablespaces_dir              | ./#innodb_temp/        |
| innodb_thread_concurrency                | 0                      |
| innodb_thread_sleep_delay                | 10000                  |
| innodb_tmpdir                            |                        |
| innodb_undo_directory                    | ./                     |
| innodb_undo_log_encrypt                  | OFF                    |
| innodb_undo_log_truncate                 | ON                     |
| innodb_undo_tablespaces                  | 2                      |
| innodb_use_native_aio                    | ON                     |
| innodb_validate_tablespace_paths         | ON                     |
| innodb_version                           | 8.0.23                 |
| innodb_write_io_threads                  | 16                     |
+------------------------------------------+------------------------+
146 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

I am open to suggestions. I am not an experienced db admin so please bear with me.

EDIT: Forgot to mention this, the table already has data from other XML files

```
mysql> select count(*) from my_tbl;
| count(*) |
+----------+
| 59108495 |
+----------+
1 row in set (7 min 56.21 sec)
```

These are the error logs from `/var/log/mysql/error.log`

```
2021-03-26T07:09:15.979529Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.23-0ubuntu0.20.04.1) starting as process 259210
2021-03-26T07:09:15.996260Z 1 [System] [MY-013576] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has started.
2021-03-26T07:09:20.080643Z 1 [System] [MY-013577] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has ended.

InnoDB: Progress in percents: 12021-03-26T07:09:20.292822Z 0 [System] [MY-011323] [Server] X Plugin ready for connections. Bind-address: '127.0.0.1' port: 33060, socket: /var/run/mysqld/mysqlx.sock
2021-03-26T07:09:20.329258Z 0 [System] [MY-010229] [Server] Starting XA crash recovery...
2021-03-26T07:09:20.338715Z 0 [System] [MY-010232] [Server] XA crash recovery finished.
2021-03-26T07:09:20.385715Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010068] [Server] CA certificate ca.pem is self signed.
2021-03-26T07:09:20.386031Z 0 [System] [MY-013602] [Server] Channel mysql_main configured to support TLS. Encrypted connections are now supported for this channel.
2021-03-26T07:09:20.434241Z 0 [System] [MY-010931] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: ready for connections. Version: '8.0.23-0ubuntu0.20.04.1'  socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'  port: 3306  (Ubuntu).
 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40 41 42 43 44 45 46 47 48 49 50 51 52 53 54 55 56 57 58 59 60 61 62 63 64 65 66 67 68 69 70 71 72 73 74 75 76 77 78 79 80 81 82 83 84 85 86 87 88 89 90 91 92 93 94 95 96 97 98 99 1002021-03-26T07:35:21.894979Z 0 [System] [MY-013172] [Server] Received SHUTDOWN from user <via user signal>. Shutting down mysqld (Version: 8.0.23-0ubuntu0.20.04.1).
2021-03-26T07:35:22.969672Z 0 [System] [MY-010910] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete (mysqld 8.0.23-0ubuntu0.20.04.1)  (Ubuntu).
2021-03-26T07:35:23.372829Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.23-0ubuntu0.20.04.1) starting as process 259662
2021-03-26T07:35:23.382151Z 1 [System] [MY-013576] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has started.
2021-03-26T07:35:23.788896Z 1 [System] [MY-013577] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has ended.
2021-03-26T07:35:23.985189Z 0 [System] [MY-011323] [Server] X Plugin ready for connections. Bind-address: '127.0.0.1' port: 33060, socket: /var/run/mysqld/mysqlx.sock
2021-03-26T07:35:24.058018Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010068] [Server] CA certificate ca.pem is self signed.
2021-03-26T07:35:24.058228Z 0 [System] [MY-013602] [Server] Channel mysql_main configured to support TLS. Encrypted connections are now supported for this channel.
2021-03-26T07:35:24.094547Z 0 [System] [MY-010931] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: ready for connections. Version: '8.0.23-0ubuntu0.20.04.1'  socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'  port: 3306  (Ubuntu).
2021-03-26T07:53:42.007890Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.23-0ubuntu0.20.04.1) starting as process 259770
2021-03-26T07:53:42.025140Z 1 [System] [MY-013576] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has started.
2021-03-26T07:53:45.447340Z 1 [System] [MY-013577] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has ended.

InnoDB: Progress in percents: 12021-03-26T07:53:45.655048Z 0 [System] [MY-011323] [Server] X Plugin ready for connections. Bind-address: '127.0.0.1' port: 33060, socket: /var/run/mysqld/mysqlx.sock
2021-03-26T07:53:45.705071Z 0 [System] [MY-010229] [Server] Starting XA crash recovery...
2021-03-26T07:53:45.714392Z 0 [System] [MY-010232] [Server] XA crash recovery finished.
2021-03-26T07:53:45.809253Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010068] [Server] CA certificate ca.pem is self signed.
2021-03-26T07:53:45.809541Z 0 [System] [MY-013602] [Server] Channel mysql_main configured to support TLS. Encrypted connections are now supported for this channel.
2021-03-26T07:53:45.854160Z 0 [System] [MY-010931] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: ready for connections. Version: '8.0.23-0ubuntu0.20.04.1'  socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'  port: 3306  (Ubuntu).
 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40 41 42 43 44 45 46 47 48 49 50 51 52 53 54 55 56 57 58 59 60 61 62 63 64 65 66 67 68 69 70 71 72 73 74 75 76 77 78 79 80 81 82 83 84 85 86 87 88 89 90 91 92 93 94 95 96 97 98 99 1002021-03-26T08:50:33.398181Z 0 [System] [MY-013172] [Server] Received SHUTDOWN from user <via user signal>. Shutting down mysqld (Version: 8.0.23-0ubuntu0.20.04.1).
2021-03-26T08:50:34.805891Z 0 [System] [MY-010910] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete (mysqld 8.0.23-0ubuntu0.20.04.1)  (Ubuntu).
2021-03-26T08:50:35.189593Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.23-0ubuntu0.20.04.1) starting as process 260012
2021-03-26T08:50:35.198967Z 1 [System] [MY-013576] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has started.
2021-03-26T08:50:35.861104Z 1 [System] [MY-013577] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has ended.
2021-03-26T08:50:35.997855Z 0 [System] [MY-011323] [Server] X Plugin ready for connections. Bind-address: '127.0.0.1' port: 33060, socket: /var/run/mysqld/mysqlx.sock
2021-03-26T08:50:36.057783Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010068] [Server] CA certificate ca.pem is self signed.
2021-03-26T08:50:36.058016Z 0 [System] [MY-013602] [Server] Channel mysql_main configured to support TLS. Encrypted connections are now supported for this channel.
2021-03-26T08:50:36.081717Z 0 [System] [MY-010931] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: ready for connections. Version: '8.0.23-0ubuntu0.20.04.1'  socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'  port: 3306  (Ubuntu).
2021-03-26T08:59:32.725975Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.23-0ubuntu0.20.04.1) starting as process 261895
2021-03-26T08:59:32.742508Z 1 [System] [MY-013576] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has started.
2021-03-26T08:59:50.946015Z 1 [System] [MY-013577] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has ended.

InnoDB: Progress in percents: 12021-03-26T08:59:51.163131Z 0 [System] [MY-011323] [Server] X Plugin ready for connections. Bind-address: '127.0.0.1' port: 33060, socket: /var/run/mysqld/mysqlx.sock
2021-03-26T08:59:51.215994Z 0 [System] [MY-010229] [Server] Starting XA crash recovery...
2021-03-26T08:59:51.229481Z 0 [System] [MY-010232] [Server] XA crash recovery finished.
2021-03-26T08:59:51.274875Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010068] [Server] CA certificate ca.pem is self signed.
2021-03-26T08:59:51.275612Z 0 [System] [MY-013602] [Server] Channel mysql_main configured to support TLS. Encrypted connections are now supported for this channel.
2021-03-26T08:59:51.317661Z 0 [System] [MY-010931] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: ready for connections. Version: '8.0.23-0ubuntu0.20.04.1'  socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'  port: 3306  (Ubuntu).
 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40 41 42 43 44 45 46 47 48 49 50 51 52 53 54 55 56 57 58 59 60 61 62 63 64 65 66 67 68 69 70 71 72 73 74 75 76 77 78 79 80 81 82 83 84 85 86 87 88 89 90 91 92 93 94 95 96 97 98 99 1002021-03-26T09:01:38.991851Z 0 [System] [MY-013172] [Server] Received SHUTDOWN from user <via user signal>. Shutting down mysqld (Version: 8.0.23-0ubuntu0.20.04.1).
2021-03-26T09:02:05.263915Z 0 [System] [MY-010910] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete (mysqld 8.0.23-0ubuntu0.20.04.1)  (Ubuntu).
2021-03-26T09:02:05.640912Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.23-0ubuntu0.20.04.1) starting as process 262009
2021-03-26T09:02:05.650539Z 1 [System] [MY-013576] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has started.
2021-03-26T09:02:05.964542Z 1 [System] [MY-013577] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has ended.
2021-03-26T09:02:06.082196Z 0 [System] [MY-011323] [Server] X Plugin ready for connections. Bind-address: '127.0.0.1' port: 33060, socket: /var/run/mysqld/mysqlx.sock
2021-03-26T09:02:06.147600Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010068] [Server] CA certificate ca.pem is self signed.
2021-03-26T09:02:06.147786Z 0 [System] [MY-013602] [Server] Channel mysql_main configured to support TLS. Encrypted connections are now supported for this channel.
2021-03-26T09:02:06.168913Z 0 [System] [MY-010931] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: ready for connections. Version: '8.0.23-0ubuntu0.20.04.1'  socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'  port: 3306  (Ubuntu).
2021-03-26T09:11:36.238684Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.23-0ubuntu0.20.04.1) starting as process 262903
2021-03-26T09:11:36.255959Z 1 [System] [MY-013576] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has started.
2021-03-26T09:11:48.086742Z 1 [System] [MY-013577] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has ended.

InnoDB: Progress in percents: 12021-03-26T09:11:48.298196Z 0 [System] [MY-011323] [Server] X Plugin ready for connections. Bind-address: '127.0.0.1' port: 33060, socket: /var/run/mysqld/mysqlx.sock
2021-03-26T09:11:48.351430Z 0 [System] [MY-010229] [Server] Starting XA crash recovery...
2021-03-26T09:11:48.361190Z 0 [System] [MY-010232] [Server] XA crash recovery finished.
2021-03-26T09:11:48.413180Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010068] [Server] CA certificate ca.pem is self signed.
2021-03-26T09:11:48.414045Z 0 [System] [MY-013602] [Server] Channel mysql_main configured to support TLS. Encrypted connections are now supported for this channel.
2021-03-26T09:11:48.458539Z 0 [System] [MY-010931] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: ready for connections. Version: '8.0.23-0ubuntu0.20.04.1'  socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'  port: 3306  (Ubuntu).
 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40 41 42 43 44 45 46 47 48 49 50 51 52 53 54 55 56 57 58 59 60 61 62 63 64 65 66 67 68 69 70 71 72 73 74 75 76 77 78 79 80 81 82 83 84 85 86 87 88 89 90 91 92 93 94 95 96 97 98 99 100
```

Comment: Are you trying to important from workbench or terminal ? Can you share error logs ?

Comment: I'm doing it from terminal in a remote server. I can share the error logs, can you please tell me how to do so? Where to look for it?

Comment: ```show global variables like 'log_error';``` check the output of this query it will return file path of error log

Comment: @JYOTIRAJAI I have added the logs to the question.

Comment: Can you give me path of ``` show global variables like 'tmpdir';``` ? check the size is available at this path .

Comment: show global variables like 'tmpdir'; - Says `/tmp`

Comment: Increase the timeout.

Comment: how much space is available at ```/tmp``` partition ?

Comment: @JYOTIRAJAI `/tmp` is mounted at the root partition, 146GB is available.

Comment: Reduce```innodb_buffer_pool_instances``` to 1, I suggest to increase buffer pool but first check with reducing this parameter value. Take a note : restart is needed.

Comment: I ended up increasing the RAM to 32gb, and I was successful. Not sure if this was specific to the machine since I started with no data in the new machine. I will debug this later this week. Sorry for the delay.