# Importing a 16 GB MySQL file silently fails

Tags: mysql, innodb, linux, mysqldump, my.cnf

I've looked at a lot answers here [MySQL any way to import a huge (32 GB) sql dump faster?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/83125/mysql-any-way-to-import-a-huge-32-gb-sql-dump-faster) and on Server Fault but haven't found a solution to not being able to import a 16 GB MySQL file completely; it silently fails at different parts of the import. Sometimes 2 GB will import before the import stops, sometimes 10 GB. There are no errors in the logs. Sometimes the console returns to #, sometimes not.

`top` shows MySQL running at 100% when importing, but then drops down to normal loads when the import stops.

The database is 16 GBs, and has 90% InnoDB tables with a few MyISAM tables. To export the database on the first machine, I'm using

```
mysqldump --single-transaction --lock-tables  -u mydatabaseuser -p mydatabase > archive.sql
```

The importing machine has 8 dedicated cores and 150 GB dedicated RAM (server is at Linode) and is running Alma Linux and MySQL 8.0.25.

To import, I'm using

```
mysql -u root -p mydatabase < archive.sql
```

Running the import from within mysql, i.e. using `mysql>` doesn't help.

One table is 12 GB, and I tried importing that table by itself with no luck.

Using these in `my.cnf` throws an error on mysql restart:

```
autocommit=0
unique_checks=0
foreign_key_checks=0
```

Should I be exporting differently?

Is MySQL on the importing machine timing out?

What do I need to edit in `my.cnf`?

**my.cnf on the importing machine:**

```
[mysqld]
disable-log-bin=1
default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password
performance-schema=0


port = 3306
socket = /tmp/mysql.sock
skip-external-locking
skip-name-resolve


# uncomment for import
bulk_insert_buffer_size = 40G
read_buffer_size = 40G


# If I uncomment these, MySQL throws the error on restart
# Job for mysqld.service failed because the control process exited with error code"
# autocommit=0
# unique_checks=0
# foreign_key_checks=0


innodb_buffer_pool_size=50G
innodb_buffer_pool_instances=56
innodb_log_file_size = 8G
innodb_log_buffer_size=64M
innodb_read_io_threads=8
innodb_write_io_threads=8
innodb_io_capacity=300

innodb_doublewrite = 0

max_allowed_packet=268435456
open_files_limit=40000
innodb_file_per_table=1

join_buffer_size=128M
sort_buffer_size=2M
read_rnd_buffer_size=2M
key_buffer_size = 20M

datadir=/var/lib/mysql
socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock

log-error=/var/log/mysqld.log
pid-file=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
```

**Edit 7/28/21**

> ```
>  mysql> SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES LIKE '%timeout%';
>
>  connect_timeout                      10       
>  delayed_insert_timeout               300      
>  have_statement_timeout               YES      
>  innodb_flush_log_at_timeout          1        
>  innodb_lock_wait_timeout             50       
>  innodb_rollback_on_timeout           OFF      
>  interactive_timeout                  28800    
>  lock_wait_timeout                    31536000 
>  mysqlx_connect_timeout               30       
>  mysqlx_idle_worker_thread_timeout    60       
>  mysqlx_interactive_timeout           28800    
>  mysqlx_port_open_timeout             0        
>  mysqlx_read_timeout                  30       
>  mysqlx_wait_timeout                  28800    
>  mysqlx_write_timeout                 60       
>  net_read_timeout                     30       
>  net_write_timeout                    60       
>  replica_net_timeout                  60       
>  rpl_stop_replica_timeout             31536000 
>  rpl_stop_slave_timeout               31536000 
>  slave_net_timeout                    60       
>  wait_timeout                         6000     
>
> mysql>  SHOW SESSION VARIABLES LIKE '%timeout%';
>
>  connect_timeout                    10       
>  delayed_insert_timeout             300      
>  have_statement_timeout             YES      
>  innodb_flush_log_at_timeout        1        
>  innodb_lock_wait_timeout           50       
>  innodb_rollback_on_timeout         OFF      
>  interactive_timeout                28800    
>  lock_wait_timeout                  31536000 
>  mysqlx_connect_timeout             30       
>  mysqlx_idle_worker_thread_timeout  60       
>  mysqlx_interactive_timeout         28800    
>  mysqlx_port_open_timeout           0        
>  mysqlx_read_timeout                30       
>  mysqlx_wait_timeout                28800    
>  mysqlx_write_timeout               60       
>  net_read_timeout                   30       
>  net_write_timeout                  60       
>  replica_net_timeout                60       
>  rpl_stop_replica_timeout           31536000 
>  rpl_stop_slave_timeout             31536000 
>  slave_net_timeout                  60       
>  wait_timeout                       28800
> ```

Comment: There isn't a configuration variable that, when set, will magically prevent your import from randomly failing. You need to identify the reason for those failures. Which logs exactly did you look at that contained no errors? How exactly _are_ you running the import?

Comment: Could it be that importing 16Gb in a single transaction is a bit too much to ask?

Comment: @mustaccio thanks, I'm using `mysql -u root -p mydatabase < archive.sql` for import. And there are no errors in the /var/log/mysqld.log

Comment: @GerardH.Pille  Break the database into smaller imports? One table is 12 GB, and I tried importing that table by itself with no luck.

Comment: Dropping 4 of the 16Gb is not what I had in mind.  You need to find out how much your database can handle in a single transaction, and split your dump according to that.  The alternative is to insert commit statements every X inserts.   I don't understand why mysqldump has no option to do that automatically, but then their enterprise products might find less customers.

Comment: Is there anything interesting in the syslog between the import start and end? I'm assuming you have the input file somewhere local on the server, where you run `mysql`, and not remotely connected.

Comment: Yes, the file is on the server; the import starts after password entry, MySQL spikes in top, and then goes back down. The # prompt returns but the import hasn't completed most of the time. It only completes once every 6-7 tries. In messages there are a lot of firewall notes, but no MySQL errors. `Jul 19 13:20:07 li575-185 kernel: Firewall: *TCP_IN Blocked* IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=f2:3c:92:04:57:5b:00:26:98:02:ab:c1:08:00 SRC=89.248.165.201 DST=192.155.84.185 LEN=40 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=244 ID=21508 PROTO=TCP SPT=44653 DPT=21489 WINDOW=1024 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those 3 settings are probably wrong.  When `autocommit=0`, nothing gets stored until a `COMMIT` is issued.

Look in the dump file; it will probably have a lot of settings, plus some huge (multi-row) `INSERTs`.  Big `INSERTs` like those work best with `autocommit=ON`.

150GB is an odd RAM size; are you sure?

These sound dangerous, even with 150G of RAM:

```
bulk_insert_buffer_size = 40G
read_buffer_size = 40G
```

They are "buffers", they don't need to be huge; 1G is probably more than ample.  Set them to 100M each.

16 is the recommended max for this:

```
innodb_buffer_pool_instances=56
```

**Timeout??**

Time it.  How long does it run?  Perhaps exactly 5 minutes?  Look for a timeout setting that is 600 (seconds).

```
SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES LIKE '%timeout%';
SHOW SESSION VARIABLES LIKE '%timeout%';
```

Comment: Thanks! Those are good ideas, and I think they help with memory usage and not running out of RAM. I do have 150GB; it's a server at Linode. But for some reason, I can get a full import once in awhile, but not for all the attempts. I don't know why it's so inconsistent. I can't open the dump file in a text editor; it's 12 gigs.

Comment: Thanks, I added the outputs in my question. The imports now appear to work, but take 3 hours for the 12 GB table

Comment: How long before it "silently failed"?

Comment: Ha, I had been watching the import for 1.5 hours, and the sizes of the tables in mysql> and PHPMyAdmin weren't changing, so I'd restart the import. Then I let it run overnight and then saw it had completed, and then narrowed it down to taking 3 hours. But your RAM settings helped.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest trying a staggered import approach, like this:

https://www.ozerov.de/bigdump/

Staggered imports allow you to tune the process based on the limitations of your server, which sometimes you have no control over.